# Set alignment to center of the image in the <li>

Tags: html, css

This is my website. http://cheaandassociates.com/

i want to set the alignment of the banner on the home page to center.

Well, this is my html,

```
<div id="contentmain">
    <div class="bannerarea">
      <div class="slideShow">
        <ul class="slides" style="height: 908px; width: 1071px; overflow: hidden; display: block;">

            <li class="slide" style="position: absolute; display: none;"><img alt="Banner1" src="images/logo48201140259.jpg" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"></li>

            <li class="slide" style="position: absolute; display: none;"><img alt="Banner2" src="images/logo48201140327.jpg" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"></li>

            <li class="slide" style="position: absolute; display: none;"><img alt="Banner3" src="images/logo48201140346.jpg" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"></li>

            <li class="slide" style="position: absolute; display: none;"><img alt="Banner4" src="images/logo48201140411.jpg" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"></li>

            <li class="slide selected" style="position: absolute; display: list-item;"><img alt="Banner5" src="images/logo48201140501.jpg" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"></li>

        </ul>
      </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                // simplest example
                $('.slideShow').slideShow({
                    interval: 20,
                    repeat: false
                });
            });
        </script>        
    </div>
  </div>
```

Images loaded over here are dynamic and their size may vary, so how can i set the images alignment to center, so that even if the width is different then i can show them quite well.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Specify a `width` on the `<li>` elements and then apply a `text-align:center`. Image elements `<img>` are [inline elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.3) so you don't have to use `margin:auto;` to center align them.

```
<li class="slide" style="position: absolute; display: none; width: 1071px; text-align:center;">
```

... and try moving all the `style` to an external CSS file ;)

Answer (score 0):

You've set a fixed width of 1071px on the ul.slides. It looks like you're trying to center with margin:auto; on the images (this is good), so if you set the width on your ul.slides to the width of your largest image (1227px), you should get the desired result.

As a side note, I'd recommend cutting back on the size of those images they are both heavy (kb) and too wide.

Comment: I don't think this will work since the `<li>` elements are absolutely positioned.